# postgres error when starting Phoenix server

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework

I Just made a new app in phoenix. Im following along with the [Programming Phoenix book](https://pragprog.com/book/phoenix/programming-phoenix). I am on chapter 3 and after making the files and using:

```
mix phoenix.server
```

I get an angry red error saying:

```
[error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.234.0>) failed to connect: ** 
(Postgrex.Error) FATAL 28000 (invalid_authorization_specification): 
role "postgres" does not exist
```

it keeps repeating this over and over.

Comment: You do not have a user named "postgres" in your postgres database.

Comment: how would I fix this? I just made the project so it's not anything I did, at least I don't think.

Comment: That depends. Generally you can start `psql` and run `create user postgres`, but you may want to add a password to the user. You will also want to add some permissions to the account. On my development machine I generally will use `create user username as superuser`. The documentation for createuser can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-createuser.html).

Comment: Just an aside--maybe next time you run into an issue like this, maybe you could take the tactic of trying to figure out if PSQL is working correctly first.  I'm pretty sure you would have seen issues directly with PSQL which needed to be addressed before you could even start thinking about Phoenix etc.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: Changes made to reflect comments.

**This will delete all local databases**

1. `rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres && initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8`
2. `sudo -u <your local username> psql postgres`
3. `CREATE USER postgres SUPERUSER;`
4. `CREATE DATABASE postgres WITH OWNER postgres;`

**This simply creates the Postgres user**

1. `psql -U postgres`
2. `CREATE USER postgres;`

Thanks @Dogbert, @mudasobwa

Comment: This is a correct approach, save for `psql -U postgres` ⇒ `CREATE USER postgres;` sequence :)

Comment: The first command will delete all the databases right? Might want to mention that clearly.